# localforage indexeddb weird keys conversion

Tags: key, indexeddb, data-conversion, localforage

I am trying to transfer entries from a mysql database (delivered by PHP via JSON) to a localforage db. The records listed under *transactions* are numbered with an id property (ascending from 1 to about 400 in the JSON string). My goal is to use these ids as keys for localforage. However the result is like shown in the screenshot from DevTools below.

```js
    var tmp, id;
    var json = JSON.parse(data); // data is the JSON encoded string returned from server
    for(var i = 0; i < json.transactions.length; i++){
      tmp = json.transactions[i];
      id = String(tmp.id);
      console.log(typeof id);
      delete tmp.id;
      transactions.setItem(id, tmp).then(function (value) {
        //console.log(value);
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
```

[resulting database in localforage in DevTools (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nZb6.png)

How can I get localforage to use the correct ids (1, 2, 3, 4 ... 400 etc.) instead of these converted keys (that seem to descend from another number system)?

Comment: do not write callback code in a for loop like this, for example see issues mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486

Answer (score 0):

The keys are strings, and so collate as "1" < "10" < "100" < "11" < "2". Presumably you want the order to be 1, 2, 10, 11, 100 ?

The underlying data store (IndexedDB) supports keys which are numbers and collate, so you could drop localforage and use IndexedDB directly.

Alternately, left-pad the strings:

`id = ("00000000" + String(tmp.id)).substr(-8);`

... which would give you: "00000001" < "00000002" < "00000010" < "00000011" < "00000100".